# How to create custom snackbar which has gradient background color in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, gradient, background-color, flutter-animation, snackbar

I am building an application using Flutter, and I am using Firebase as an backend. Suddenly, I need to use snackbar to show the user message about authentication. For example: *user-not-found*, *password or email is wrong*. Then I used default snackbar, it worked pretty well, but I wanted it to be appealing on the eye. So eye created custom snackbar, needless to say I used chatgpt for some parts. Here is how you can create custom snackbar with the gradient background color.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomGradientSnackbar {
   final String text;
   final Gradient gradient;
   final Color textColor;

   CustomGradientSnackbar({
    required this.text,
    required this.gradient,
    required this.textColor,
  });

  void show(BuildContext context) {
    OverlayState? overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
    OverlayEntry overlayEntry;

    overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: Material(
          elevation: 6.0,
          child: Container(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 10.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
             gradient: gradient,
            ),
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: textColor,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    overlayState.insert(overlayEntry);

    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2)).then((_) {
      overlayEntry.remove();
    });
  }
}
```

Result:

[image: Final result]

If anyone knows better way of creating custom gradient snackbar, feel free to answer.

Comment: Try this: https://pub.dev/packages/another_flushbar

Comment: Thanks. It has nice animation, but it does not support gradient color. If somebody help to animate mine, I would appreciate it. @Aks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Flushbar(
              // title: "User not found",
              // message: 'User not found.',
              messageText: const Text(
                'User not found',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
              backgroundGradient: const LinearGradient(colors: [
                Color(0xffD95F30),
                Color.fromRGBO(181, 120, 44, 1),
                Color.fromRGBO(167, 149, 48, 1)
              ]), //here's the gradient support

            ).show(context);
          },
          child: const Text('click'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FancySnackbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVUkn.jpg) also.Installation guide: Add this snippet code to your dependencies in pubspec.yaml file:

```
fancy_snackbar:
git:
  url: https://github.com/MR0100/fancy_snackbar.git
```

Usage:

```
import 'package:fancy_snackbar/fancy_snackbar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(const MySnackBar());
}

class MySnackBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const MySnackBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: ["success", "error", "waitting", "info", "warning"]
              .map((e) => GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      // Get the text of the button that was pressed
                      String buttonText = e;

                      // Set the message of the snackbar
                      String message = '';

                      switch (buttonText) {
                        case "success":
                          message =
                              "You have successfully pressed the success 
                                 button";
                          FancySnackbar.showSnackbar(
                            context,
                            snackBarType: FancySnackBarType.success,
                            title: "Success",
                            message: message,
                            duration: 2,
                            onCloseEvent: () {},
                          );
                          break;
                        case "error":
                          message = "You have pressed the error button";
                          FancySnackbar.showSnackbar(
                            context,
                            snackBarType: FancySnackBarType.error,
                            title: "Error",
                            message: message,
                            duration: 2,
                            onCloseEvent: () {},
                          );
                          break;
                        case "waiting":
                          message = "You have pressed the waiting button";
                           FancySnackbar.showSnackbar(
                            context,
                            snackBarType: FancySnackBarType.waiting,
                            title: "Waiting",
                            message: message,
                            duration: 2,
                            onCloseEvent: () {},
                          );
                          break;
                        case "info":
                          message = "You have pressed the info button";
                          FancySnackbar.showSnackbar(
                            context,
                            snackBarType: FancySnackBarType.info,
                            title: "Info",
                            message: message,
                            duration: 2,
                            onCloseEvent: () {},
                          );
                          break;
                        case "warning":
                          message = "You have pressed the warning button";
                          FancySnackbar.showSnackbar(
                            context,
                            snackBarType: FancySnackBarType.warning,
                            title: "Warning",
                            message: message,
                            duration: 2,
                            onCloseEvent: () {},
                          );
                          break;
                      }

                      // Show a snackbar with the message
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: Text(e),
                    ),
                  ))
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVUkn.jpg)

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56mc0.jpg)

[Waiting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbEX0.jpg)

[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pr8FX.jpg)

[Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G63Ee.jpg)

It does not support gradient, but I hope it is going to help somebody.

Comment: Please try to understand what the questioner is asking about. The questioner asked for the gradient, not a fancy or decorative one.